# Requiring a directives controller alongside other required controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a pair of directives, one lives within the other and requires it using `require: '^parentTag'`. The two directives also declare their own controllers. Inside of the parent directive I can access its controller as the fourth argument to `link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl)` but in the child this fourth argument is either the required controller or an array of required controllers and the directives controller is no longer accessible.

I've tried to require the controller using the name used in `controllerAs 'vm'` and also by using the string name for the controller. Neither gets the controller back into that fourth argument.

The controller is accessible from the scope as `scope.vm` but I'd like to access it via that fourth argument if possible.

This Plunkr shows that the ChildController is not in the fourth argument and only on the scope but the ParentController is accessible as the fourth argument.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2WmB6Bqgc8MEG9JWz4wt

Comment: please have a look here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate

Answer (score 1):

You could require the same directive by its name (never seen anyone actually do it):

```
function ChildTag() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: ['^parentTag', 'childTag'],
    scope: {},
    template: '<div class="child-tag">Child</div>',
    link: link,
    controller: ChildController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  }

  function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude) {
      // ctrls[1] is ChildController
      console.log('Child vm not found in ctrls', ctrls);
      console.log('Child vm found on scope', scope.vm);
  }
}
```